# How to do routing for subdomain and configure it to require certificate in ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, subdomain

I want to do routing for subdomain in one ASP NET Core project. Is it possible? E.g. when I have endpoint `/test`, I would to have it at subdomain e.g. `https://testing.myapp.com/test`, but not at `https://myapp.com/test`. How can I do it, and if it's possible, how to configure the subodamin e.g to require client certificate?

Comment: 2 things of interest: 

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-endpoints-using-server-name-indication

2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#host-matching-in-routes-with-requirehost

Comment: I did `[Host("mtls.*")]` on my action in controller, but now I'm getting 404 error. My goal is to have something like this: `https://mtls.localhost:8080/endpoint`. What did I wrong?